# get array out of loop

Tags: php, loops

I need get array out of loop (I need used array, and not, last value)

loop

```
for ($x = 1; $x < $numero; $x++) {
$frase = $frase_script[$x];
$distrito1 = (explode(',',$frase));

echo $distrito1[0]}
```

Variable out

```
$ultimo_nome = $distrito1[0];
```

I need used array, and not, last value

```
echo "<br> I need print array, and not, last value".$ultimo_nome;
```

error: prints the last value and not an array.

[Example](http://apoiarmais.com/teste/teste.php)

all code

```
 $ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=country=pt&lang=pt&q=lisbon&fcode=ADM2&adminCode1=14&style=SHORT&maxRows=1000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Accept: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$frase_script = (explode(',',$response));

$frase = $frase_script[0];
$palavra = (explode(':',$frase));
$numero = $palavra[1];    

$frase_script = (explode('"name":',$response));

echo '[';

for ($x = 1; $x < $numero; $x++) {
    $frase = $frase_script[$x];
    $distrito1 = (explode(',',$frase));

    echo $distrito1[0]; }


$ultimo_nome = $distrito1[0];

echo $ultimo_nome;


echo ']';

echo "<br> I need print array, and not, last value".$ultimo_nome;
```

Comment: _error: prints the last value and not an array...._ `echo` doesn't print arrays

Comment: Are you trying to decode or write json on your own?

Comment: Can you include the value of `$response` and what you are expecting as output?

Comment: I am expecting as output, for example: the value 4 in the position of the array

Answer (score 0):

if you need print all the elements but not the lasy you could  use

```
$distrito1 = (explode(',',$frase));
$numElem = count($distrito1); 

foreach ($distrito1 as $key => $value){
  if ( $key < $numElem-1 ){
     echo $value;
  } else {
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: your comment is not clear  .. explain  better  .. .. i don't see  any "query"  in you code  .and in your question  ..